# MS Word: Linked doesn't not show entire subdocument, only one page of it

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Word 2016 and trying to create a master document with subdocuments. I add the subdocument by clicking Insert -> Object -> Object and in the dialog box, select Create From File tab, click link to file, and then select the document I want as the subdocument. It appears to work because the subdocument is showing, but you cannot see the entire subdocument.  It appears to show only one page of the linked subdocument.

I've also tried going into Outline view, clicking on Show Document, Insert, and then selecting my subdocument. That seems like it should work, but no document is inserted or shows.

Is there an option to show the entire subdocument or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### The Master Document "Feature" is seriously flawed!

See [my page on this](https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart).

> **How can I best use the Master Document feature?**
>
> General Answer: With Word 95-Word 2021, don't use it.
>
> It has serious bugs and will corrupt your entire document at the most
> inconvenient time possible. (This advice to not use Master Documents
> reported as correct through Word 2021.) John McGhie put it succinctly
> when he said that "there are two kinds of Master Documents: Those that
> are corrupt and those that will be corrupt soon." It was reported
> fixed in Word 2007, but "The jury is in: The Master Document feature
> in Word 2010 remains word processing's answer to Conan the Destroyer.
> Use it only if you enjoy pain and frustration." Microsoft Word 2010
> Bible by Herb Tyson, MVP. "Since its inception, the Master Documents
> feature has been a bit quirky and buggy, and that fact hasn't changed
> with Word 2010, unfortunately."  by Faithe Wempen, p. 681 This comment
> has been updated without change (other than the year) in Microsoft
> Word 2013 In Depth and Microsoft Word 2016 In Depth.

---

> Keep in mind that Word will handle fairly large documents, assuming
> you have the processor and RAM to deal with it. Second, there are
> reasonable work-arounds available.
>
> MVP Graham Mayor created a powerful utility that can replace Master
> Documents for some purposes: [Boiler - Insert a selection of documents](http://www.gmayor.com/Boiler.htm)
> by Graham Mayor, MVP
>
> MVP John Korchok recommends creating Master Documents to print and
> then throwing them away. I agree that is a viable use of this feature.
> https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2013/10/modular-documents/
> (archival link) I would recommend creating a new folder for this
> purpose and copying anything to go into the MD to this folder, never
> use your original documents as part of a MD.

---

> **The opening statement may be too strong.**
>
> The general rule might better be phrased "Don't edit Master
> Documents!" You can use the feature to generate something to print.
> You can use it to get Word to split up result documents from mail
> merge into separate files. But when you are done with the Master
> Document it should be deleted before it corrupts your subs.
>
> Steve Hudson (aka the Word Heretic) has apparently mastered Master
> Documents and provides [detailed instructions](http://www.techwr-l.com/articles/general/masterdocs) on when their use is
> appropriate, how do to it, with strict rules to follow. These are only
> for those who are willing and able to follow the instructions. If you
> are inclined to skip steps or ignore his warnings see the general answer
> above. If using his work, please see [my supplemental page](https://addbalance.com/word/MasterDocHudson.htm#PageStart).

---

I apologize for not telling you how to use this, but I've seen stories of people losing novels and doctoral theses because of using it. I've seen reports of parts of a Master Document that are not even open being corrupted.

See also my page on [Outlining in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm).

### You can insert documents directly into a document not using the Master Document Feature

Under the Insert tab, use Insert Object, Text From File. You can insert the text directly, or as a link. When you insert as a link, the whole becomes a bit more difficult to move because you need to move all parts together.

Comment: Thank you for that great bit of information.  In my frustration, I actually ended up using the "Insert Text From File as a link" and seems to work... mostly.  Few quirks there too.  Sometimes I can change in the "master" doc and it updates the source, sometimes not.  I don't know if it's supposed to or not! ;-)